# How to understand these two propositions?

Tags: logic

I have these two propositions:

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \exists \varepsilon >0, x<\varepsilon$

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon >0, |x|<\varepsilon$

I don't know how to read them, can you help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘read them’? Understand what they mean, or what  they imply?

Comment: What they mean , for exemple is the first means that R is bounded ? @almagest

Comment: oh ok, so how to prove that the first is right ?

Comment: almagest already gave that in a comment..

Comment: yes but how we explain that For all real 
x
 we can find a positivel 
ϵ
 greater than 

Comment: @almagest we use Archimed?

Comment: What is Archimed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property

Answer (score 1):

> $$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \exists \varepsilon >0, x<\varepsilon$$

"For any real $x$ there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $x$ is less than $\varepsilon$."

> $$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon >0, |x|<\varepsilon$$

"For any real $x$ and for any positive $\varepsilon $, the absolute value of $x$ is less than $\varepsilon$."

Comment: How to prove the first one ?

Comment: That's a whole other question, @PolineSandra.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "read them" you mean how to interpreted them in English.

**So take the first proposition:**

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \exists \varepsilon >0, x<\varepsilon$

This proposition consists of 3 parts:

1. the quantifier: $\forall x$. The 
   $\forall $ is the symbol for universal quantification, meaning that the predicate must hold for all elements of the domain in order to be true.
2. the domain : $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is translated to: x is in the set of Real numbers. So as your domain you have all the real numbers.
3. a predicate : $\exists \varepsilon >0, x<\varepsilon$
   is the predicate that should be true for all the elements of the real numbers. The $\exists$ is the symbol for existential quantification, meaning there should exist (at least) one element in the domain of numbers > 0 where the predicate x < ε will be true.

So to put it as a whole:

"For all real numbers, there exists a positive number so that x < ε"

Which is true because we can take  <s>ε = x + 1</s>

for any $x$ we can take $\varepsilon = |x| + 1$

*The positive value of x + 1*

**For the second proposition:**

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon >0, |x|<\varepsilon$

The predicate $x < \varepsilon$ is replaced with $|x|<\varepsilon$

The quantifier "∃ε" is replaced with "∀ε"

So this translates to:

<s>"For all real numbers, there exists a positive number so that the absolute value of x < ε"</s>

Which is also true because we can always take ε = x + 1

"For all real numbers, it holds that for all positive numbers, the absolute value of x < ε"

Which is false because take any x $\neq$ 0 or 1 and take ε = 1. This is one example so that "|x| < ε" is false.

Hence $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon >0, |x|<\varepsilon$ is not true.

**Correction to second proposition:**

1. Pointed out that the existential quantifier "∃ε" is being changed to the universal quantifier "∀ε" as opposed to the first proposition.
2. Corrected the translation.
3. Corrected the outcome of the second proposition from being true, to being false.

**Edit to answer the additional question of @Poline Sandra in the comment under this answer.**

The question being whether or not the second statement:
$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon >0, |x|<\varepsilon$
being true or false because $x = 6$ and $ε = 4$ yields that $|x| < ε$ will be false since |6| is not smaller than 4.

You are correct, during answering this question I discovered that I accidentally missed out that the quantifier over ε was different in the second proposition.

Since this is an universal quantification over ε the predicate must hold for all x **and** also for all ε. By taking an x and ε that results into false you show that the universal quantification is not true, because it must hold for all elements in its domain to be true.

So I corrected the answer. My apologies and I hope it didn't confuse you.

---

Comment: but in the second there exists x=6 and there exists $\varepsilon =4$, $6\geq 4$ so the second statement is false ??? @JoshuaRMS

Comment: I corrected my answer and hope that this also answered your additional question. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

@JoshuaRMS answered in detail what the two statements mean. There is no point in repeating that.

But in comments, the OP asked a supplementary question: how do you prove the two statements?

I gave the short answer in an early comment under the question: take $\epsilon=|x|+1$. That proves both statements.

---

But the OP appeared to want a lot of detail, referring back to the axioms. A rough summary is as follows:

You use the following axioms:

(1) there is a total order $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$

(2) the number 1 belongs to $\mathbb{R}$,

(3) $1>0$

(4) if $a,b$ belong to $\mathbb{R}$, then so does $a+b$.

(5) each element $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ has an inverse $-a$;

(6) if $a<0$, then $-a>a$; and if $a>0$ then $a>-a$

(7) if $a>0$, then $b+a>b$.

---

For the first statement, you are told that $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}$.

By (2) 1 is also in $\mathbb{R}$, and by (3) $1>0$

By (1) we have either $x\ge0$ or $x\le0$.

If $x\ge0$, then take $\epsilon=1+x$. By (4), $\epsilon$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, so by 
(7), $\epsilon>x$.

If $x<0$, then [by (5)] $-x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$, and [by (6)] $-x>0$, so take $\epsilon=-x$. By (6) we have $\epsilon>x$.

That establishes the first proposition.

---

But it now turns out (several days later) that the OP did not want a detailed proof from the axioms! The OP simply didn't understand what they meant, but finally realised that the second proposition $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon >0, |x|<\varepsilon$ was false, read @Shaun's entirely correct answer, and gave a counter-example: 6 is not less than 4! Because I, @JoshuaRMS, and several people writing comments had all misread the question (because we expected the second part to be $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \exists \varepsilon >0, |x|<\varepsilon$). Actually, the second quantifier is another $\forall$. So I had failed to heed the classic advice of "read the question"!

Comment: but in the second there exists x=6 and there exists $\varepsilon=4$ such that $6\geq 4$ @almagest